# will ptpd affect the app crash ios8

Tags: ios8

I am getting an ptpd crash as shown in below. It is in crash log along with my app crash in Device logs, I presume that it is causing my app crash. Any idea what is this ptpd crash do? and what is this **PLManagedObjectContext**
**Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.PLManagedObjectContext.ChangeHub
    Thread 4 Crashed:**

```
Incident Identifier: 1B7765B9-4717-4E1A-AD72-47DCB3618096
CrashReporter Key:   08c57bf283a25fa3cac64c3818d305cc9917ebab
Hardware Model:      iPad4,2
Process:             ptpd [8509]
Path:                /usr/libexec/ptpd
Identifier:          ptpd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-03-10 14:57:04.610 +0000
Launch Time:         2015-03-10 14:40:32.704 +0000
OS Version:          iOS 8.0.2 (12A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  4

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18343a084 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x193e8c0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x183439f44 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 116
3   Foundation                      0x1842b9fc0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 88
4   PhotoLibraryServices            0x18e04d6ac __addContextToList_block_invoke + 488
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1944d149c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1944d145c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1944db554 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1216
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1944d4564 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 132
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1944dd224 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 656
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1944de75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1946ad2e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1946acfa8 start_wqthread + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945f8eb8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001946a59e0 _os_semaphore_wait + 20
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944da474 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 516
3   CoreData                        0x000000018318d464 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 216
4   CoreData                        0x0000000183192f0c -[NSManagedObjectContext(NSEditorAndEditorRegistration) setName:] + 132
5   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018e03eef4 +[PLManagedObjectContext contextForPhotoLibrary:name:] + 304
6   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018dfbf054 -[PLPhotoLibrary loadDatabase:] + 608
7   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018dfb54ec -[PLPhotoLibrary initWithTransientContext:name:] + 552
8   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018e086cbc -[PLPTPdAssetManager photoLibrary] + 116
9   PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018e0890c8 -[PLPTPdAssetManager(PictureTransferProtocol) libraryIsAvailable] + 20
10  ptpd                            0x00000001000a7eac 0x100098000 + 65196
11  ptpd                            0x00000001000b4748 0x100098000 + 116552
12  ptpd                            0x000000010009b6a8 0x100098000 + 13992
13  ptpd                            0x000000010009f0d0 0x100098000 + 28880
14  IOKit                           0x000000018457dd14 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 264
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833dcf30 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833f1b34 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833f1a94 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 432
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833efa14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
19  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018331d660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
20  ptpd                            0x00000001000b464c 0x100098000 + 116300
21  ptpd                            0x00000001000b51e0 0x100098000 + 119264
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001944faa04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945f8c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944e097c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944d34a0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945f8e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001945f8cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833f1804 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ef758 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018331d660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018336f718 CFRunLoopRun + 108
6   ImageCapture                    0x000000018ca95380 -[PTPTransport callbackThreadFunction] + 304
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946afe7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946afdd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946acfac thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194613c78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946ad390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946acfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.PLManagedObjectContext.ChangeHub
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194613270 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946b1224 pthread_kill + 108
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019458ab14 abort + 108
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193671414 abort_message + 112
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193690b88 default_terminate_handler() + 300
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193e8c3bc _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019368dbb0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019368d474 __cxa_throw + 132
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000193e8c200 objc_exception_throw + 344
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183439f40 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 112
10  Foundation                      0x00000001842b9fbc -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 84
11  PhotoLibraryServices            0x000000018e04d6a8 __addContextToList_block_invoke + 484
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944d1498 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944d1458 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944db550 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1212
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944d4560 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 128
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944dd220 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 652
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001944de758 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946ad2e0 _pthread_wqthread + 812
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001946acfa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000013f923d27
    x4: 0x0000000193691dfd   x5: 0x00000001024f2800   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000f80
    x8: 0x000000000c000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000002  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001024f4000  x21: 0x00000001981b9ce8  x22: 0x000000013f954d90  x23: 0x0000000197298000
   x24: 0x0000000188393814  x25: 0x000000013f95af70  x26: 0x0000000000010001  x27: 0x00000001972a00fc
   x28: 0x000000000000000f  fp: 0x00000001024f2760   lr: 0x00000001946b1228
    sp: 0x00000001024f2740   pc: 0x0000000194613270 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet this problem when I use the ALAssetsLibrary. When using the ARC, we can't make sure if the ALAssetsLibrary object is destoried. So we can create a singleton ALAssetsLibrary object to solve this problem. You can checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693118/3103450. Hope this helpful to you : )